Sum of the angle bisectors and sum of side lengths
In The Secrets of Triangles by Posamentier and Lehmann, page 274, it says

The sum of the angle bisectors can be further refined as Sefket
Arslanagic (2010) showed with the following:
$t_a+t_b+t_c<a+b+c$; and, furthermore, we can state that
$t_a+t_b+t_c\leq \frac{3}{2}(a+b+c)$.
However, we should note that the equality of the last relationship
only holds true for equilateral triangles, where $a=b=c$ and
$t_a=t_b=t_c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$.

I think the coefficient $\frac{3}{2}$ should be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Can anyone find the reference by Sefket? I cannot find it online. Thanks.

I don't understand your "furthermore" and the inequality which follows it... Haven't you reversed one of the inequalities ?

I have the same doubt. That's why I want to read Sefket's statement and proof. (I have quoted it to make it clearer.)

I would like to add for context that right before this, they proved that $t_a+t_b+t_c\leq \frac{3}{2}(a+b+c)$, so then the next logical progressions would be $t_a+t_b+t_c\leq 1(a+b+c)$ and $t_a+t_b+t_c\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a+b+c)$

I have figured out the proof by myself. Thanks Jake's Lamp.

We prove
\begin{equation*}
t_a+t_b+t_c\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a+b+c)=\sqrt{3}s.
\end{equation*}
where $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. By the formulas in the same book on page 109, we have
\begin{align*}
t_a=&\frac{2\sqrt{bcs(s-a)}}{b+c}\leq \sqrt{s(s-a)}; \\
t_b=&\frac{2\sqrt{cas(s-b)}}{c+a}\leq \sqrt{s(s-b)}; \\
t_c=&\frac{2\sqrt{abs(s-c)}}{a+b}\leq \sqrt{s(s-c)};
\end{align*}
Now it suffices to show
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{s-a}+\sqrt{s-b}+\sqrt{s-c}\leq \sqrt{3s}.
\end{equation*}
This is simply due to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{equation*}
(\sqrt{s-a}+\sqrt{s-b}+\sqrt{s-c})^2\leq 3(s-a+s-b+s-c)=3s.
\end{equation*}
Done.

see the solution given here

Thank you. Most inequalities there are too complicated for me...

I should have said that it is the last solution (by Maths_1729) you should consider.

Thanks. I just got it.
